# Ruby on Rails POST request fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, post

Here the thing goes, I wanna write a login in a page in Ruby on Rails, when the url is `localhost:3000/admin`, I'll get the page which need to fill in. After the form has filled in, I submit the button and the form should be admitted to the `create` action with `post` method, however it still works with `get` method and `new` action.

What happens to it?

Here is the `routes.rb` file:

```
     Prefix Verb          URI Pattern                Controller#Action
new_admin_users GET      /admin/users/new(.:format)  admin/users#new
   admin_users  POST     /admin/users(.:format)      admin/users#create
         admin  GET      /admin(.:format)            admin/users#new
                POST     /admin(.:format)            admin/users#create
    posts_home  GET      /posts/home(.:format)       redirect(301, /posts)
   posts_about  GET      /posts/about(.:format)      redirect(301, /about)
```

Then here is the new action

```
  <form class="form-signin">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <%= form_for :user,url:admin_users_path do |f| %>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :name%><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name ,class:"form-control" %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :pass%><br>
        <%= f.text_field :pass,class:"form-control" %>
      </p>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <p>
        <%= f.submit'Sign in', :class=>"btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" %>
      </p>
      <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
    <%end%>
  </form>
```

Here is the `routes.rb`:

```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do
     namespace :admin do
       resources :users
       get "",  to:"users#new"
       post "", to:"users#create"
     end
     get "/posts/home",  to: redirect("/posts")
     get "/posts/about", to: redirect("/about")
     resources :posts do
       resources :comments
     end
     root "posts#index"
     get "/home",to: "posts#index"
     get "/about",to: "posts#about"
   end
```

If you have some throught, please tell me, thanks in advance!

Comment: The `routes.rb` you shared, it looks like the resault of `rake routes`. Please put `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: sorry ,I forget it .here is the code of routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

You must have the actual `User` object built inside your controller. Try using that inside your form instead of symbol `:user`.

```
<%= form_for @user, url: admin_users_path do |f| %>
...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try explicitly specifying the method post
Instead of

```
<%= form_for :user,url:admin_users_path do |f| %>
```

Use this:

```
 <%= form_for :user,url:admin_users_path, method: :post do |f| %>
```

Also check the created action in form created such way

Hope this Helps

Comment: sorry to tell you the method doesn't work ,thanks anyway,you are a warm-hearted man~